# Can I connect to the internet and talk to device that's recognized as a network adapter device at the same time?

Tags: windows-10, network-adapter

I have an issue that is as follows: We have a device that connects to the PC and is recognized as a network adapter. When we do this, we can no longer talk to our databases, connect to the internet, etc. We can only talk to this device.

This started when we upgraded a computer from windows 7 to windows 10. On windows 7 we were able to talk to the device and the outside world while connected, and on windows 10 we can only talk to one or the other. Is there a way to be able to talk to this device and the outside work at the same time on windows 10? The obvious work around is to talk disconnect the device when we need to talk to a database, but that'll be a mounting frustration for those who have to work with this device and would like to avoid just doing that.

Comment: It sounds like your default gateway gets changed to be the device when you plug it in. Check your routing tablel. Might help if you can say what the device is.

Comment: I don't think I can outright say what the device is, but I can say it's not a household device; it's something used in the medical field. The device is connected via USB and communicated with using its IP address, at least at the point I'm interested in (during manufacturing of said device) I'll check the routing table and see if I can figure anything out there.

Comment: Without knowing the device make and model, predicting how it will act is unlikely.